# Can I match forEach variable within document.querySelectorAll function

Tags: javascript, match, nodelist, queryselector

I am trying to refactor my **document.querySelectorAll** code combining several classes/types together in one function rather than have several functions perfoming the same task but for a different class/type.

```
Sample

document.querySelectorAll("button[name='checkout']","input[name='checkout']");

x.forEach(el => el.setAttribute("disabled","disabled"))
```

This works to match on the first match (the button element), but it does not match for every class after that (ie the input element).

How do I adjust my code to get my desired result of disabling both the button and the input?

Comment: What do you mean by `this works to match on the first match, but it does not match for every class that is found`? `.cart-recap` elements are found but `.checkout-buttons` and `.payment-button` are not?

Comment: @dork that is correct. The last time I checked it did not work that way.

Comment: @dork I have updated my question's description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`querySelectorAll` takes only a single argument, not two. You can however pass a [single selector list that matches multiple elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Selector_list):

```
document.querySelectorAll("button[name='checkout'], input[name='checkout']");
//                                                ^^
```

Comment: Thank you! This is the answer I was looking for.